# Allure Report: Hyperlink For Story

Tags: allure

Is there a way to make the value in @Stories annotation to be a hyperlink? So that user can click on it and open a page.

Comment: Relates to https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/311.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in the @Story now cannot be used as link.
Now you just can provide property for testcase and it can be link. We have an example of this approach on [our teamcity](http://teamcity.qatools.ru/repository/download/allure_core_master_deploy/1073:id/index.html#/home/2f339f3808b4849a/e34f0d59c885221a) (click "login as guest" to get in). There  you can see  the url of the tested page above the steps block. It is clickable and leads to tested page.

If these way is not suitable for you, please [report an issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core) and give more infromation about your use-cases of this feature

Comment: Can you please provide an example (code snippet) of how to use (or provide) property in the test case and make it a link? I am using TestNG framework.

Comment: See the following wiki page: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Parameters This is usable starting since Allure 1.4.0.RC5 and will be certainly included to 1.4.0 release.